# Flutter : Am integrating PayPal subscription API for recurring payment purpose, I am not able to find any working Solution for that

Tags: flutter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Flutter: Am integrating PayPal subscription API for recurring payment purpose, I am not able to find any working solution for that,

Can anyone give me a working solution for PayPal recurring payment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can create a paypal subscription plan on your business account.
After that (there's a wizard) you can copy the button link to subscribe into your code.

The hardest part is to manage your subscriptions.. you can use the cUrl APIs that you can find here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/
or, probably, find how to translate it into your programming language.

This guide can also help you https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/

Hope this hints can help you!
I struggled with this too, there's not much documentation online